# Set IP address routing to default without restarting PC?

Tags: networking, command-line, routing

I have been testing on routing command in the windows shell e.g. `route add 172.10.10.2 mask 255.255.0.0 10.10.8.9`.

After all these tests, the routing table is pretty messed up, and I had to reboot Windows so the proper routing is initiated again.

Is there any command, that I can run/batch file, such that it restores the routing table without rebooting?

I have tried disabling the network adapter and that does not seem to do it either.

Comment: If you are testing and not completely sure of what you are doing (I don't mean that rudely), a reboot might be the only way to ensure you clean it up well.

Comment: actually, i have a script that does routing to do other work, but after a work is done, i run another script to delete some routes, and it caused the network to not function properly.

Rather, than writing a delete route script, if there is a there is a faster method where i can restore the routing table, i would perform the other route, rather than rebooting the pc.